# Сравнение имени ПК и ввод значений, которые будут назначениы его имени в Python

Tags: python

как можно использовать имя ПК, как основопологающую в скрипте?
В чём моя идея
Скрипт проверяет имя ПК и использует значения, которые для него прописаны.
Пример
Имя ПК - B1
Будут использваться значения для originmail и originpassword, которые прописаны для B1
Имя ПК - B26
Будут использваться значения для originmail и originpassword, которые прописаны для B26

Comment: Вы желаете получить имя ПК или что?

Comment: Проще будет описать действия, которые я хотел бы получить в виде кода
1. Указывается некий набор имён ПК, к которым будут прописаны переменные, например, mail и password
2. Скрипт смотрит имя ПК
3. Скрипт вводит данные, которые привязаны к имени ПК.
Если нужно, могу изобразить действие скрипта при помощи кода, написанного на AutoIt